# Read only the numbers from a txt file python

Tags: python, math

I have a text file that contains these some words and a number written with a point in it. For example
`hello!
54.123`

Now I only want the number 54.123 to be extracted an converted so that the outcome is `54123`

The code I tried is

```
import re
exp = re.compile(r'^[\+]?[0-9]')

my_list = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if re.match(exp, line.strip()):
            my_list.append(int(line.strip()))

#convert to a string
listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in my_list])
print(listToStr)
```

But this returns the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '54.123'

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Well, what do you make of that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to convert the current line to a float. In case the line does not contain a legit float number it returns a ValueError exception that you can catch and just pass. If no exception is thrown just split the line at the dot, join the 2 parts, convert to int and add to the array.

```
my_list = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        try:
            tmp = float(line)
            num = int(''.join(line.split(".")))
            my_list.append(num)
        except ValueError:
            pass

#convert to a string
listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in my_list])
print(listToStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help I am now getting numbers from the file I guess you were trying to use split in place of strip

```
import re
exp = re.compile(r'[0-9]')

my_list = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        for numbers in line.split():
            if re.match(exp, numbers):
                my_list.append(numbers)

#convert to a string
listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in my_list])
print(listToStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a given line is a string representing a number using the `isdigit()` function.

From what I can tell you need to just check if there is a number as `isdigit()` works on integers only (floats contain "." which isn't a number and it returns False).

**For example:**

```
def numCheck(string):
  # Checks if the input string contains numbers
  return any(i.isdigit() for i in string)

string = '54.123'
print(numCheck(string)) # True

string = 'hello'
print(numCheck(string)) # False
```

Note: if your data contains things like `123ab56` then this won't be good for you.

---

To convert 54.123 to 54123 you could use the `replace(old, new)` function.

**For example:**

```
string = 54.123
new_string = string.replace('.', '') # replace . with nothing
print(new_string) # 54123
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I will look into it!